# Python I/O info not being written to .txt file

Tags: python, list, file-io

So, i am trying to write the values to each list from the loop...multiply hours by 20 and then write out to file "workers.txt".

The file is created by the script, but no data is written to it. I'm at my wits end, which is fairly common.

```
with open('workers.txt', 'a') as filet:
    emp_num = [] #i am trying to write data 3 times to these lists
    emp_name = []
    hours = []
    pay = [0]

i = 0
take = 0
for i in range(3):
    emp_num.append(input('Employee ID: '))
    emp_name.append(input('Employee Name: '))
    hours.append(float(input('Hours: ')))
    pay.append(float(input(hours * 20)))
    i += 1

print(emp_num)
print(emp_name)
print(hours)
print(pay)

filet.close()
```

Comment: You should write to the file. `print`, by default, writes to standard output (`sys.stdout`). Try with: `print(emp_num, file=filet)`.

Comment: you're not even writing to the file... and your file is closed as soon as you exit `with`

Comment: Also, `for i in range(1):` says to perform the loop once, with `i` set to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating empty lists in the `with` statement doesn't map them to the file. You still need to actually call `filet.write`.

```
def make_employee():
    num = input("Employee ID: ")
    name = input("Employee name: ")
    hours = input("Hours: ")
    pay = float(hours) * 20
    return (num, name, hours, pay)


with open('workers.txt', 'a') as filet:
    for i in range(10):  # E.g., 10 employees
        num, name, hours, pay = make_employee()
        filet.write("{} {} {} {}\n".format(num, name, hours, pay))
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function, by default, writes to [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout). If you want it to write to the file you opened, you should use the `file` keyword argument.

```
with open('workers.txt', 'a') as fout:
    emp_num = []
    emp_name = []
    hours = []
    pay = []

    # add 3 employees (user input -> lists)
    for i in range(3):
        emp_num.append(input('Employee ID: '))
        emp_name.append(input('Employee Name: '))
        hours.append(float(input('Hours: ')))
        pay.append(float(input(hours * 20)))

    # print lists' content to the file we opened
    print(emp_num, file=fout)
    print(emp_name, file=fout)
    print(hours, file=fout)
    print(pay, file=fout)
```

Also, note that context manager will close the file on exit - that's why all your file-related operations have to be within the `with` block.

Answer (score 1):

```
some_list = list()
with open('workers.txt') as filet:  # it is context manager, no need to close file manually
    for line in filet:  # read file line by line, saves operative memory
        some_list.append(line.strip())  # delete line wrapping

print(some_list)
```